# PowerShell Script to sync members of distribution group with SharePoint group

Tags: powershell, activerecord, sharepoint-2013

Im in a SharePoint environment where:

- distribution lists are in use instead of security lists
- can not switch to security list
- distribution lists are nested
- no user profile sync

So to sync my new SharePoint group "something" I was thinking of running a PowerShell script regulary to fetch all the members hierarchically and put them in the SharePoint group, including checks. Unfortunately I cant install the AD add-in so I installed the Quest AD add-in.

*update*: I noticed that direct syncing took too long. So I have decided to split the solution: the first AD script output all nested distribution groups (Get-QADGroupMember -Indirect -Type 'group'), although this takes as long as getting all users, this feels safer, since probably this doesnt have to been run that much. Then script 2 read the groups and creates a csv file per group, this is certainly not unique, but with tens of thousands of users, this is the safest way. Then script 3 (underneath) reads the csv files with users and update the SharePoint user group. Then script 4 reads again the usergroup and deletes all the one where the date (in notes) is not equal to the most recent date.

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Syncs All Users in AD distribution Group To SharePoint group:
    - Adds new Users
    - Updates display name, email when changed
    - Deleted Users no longer present
#>
# --------------------------------------------------------
# Variables to Change / Set:
# --------------------------------------------------------
$site = "http://abc-def-ghi:7777"
$SPgroup = "MYCOOLSPGROUP"
$ADgroup = "MYADGROUP"    

# --------------------------------------------------------
# Add-SSuser : adds a user to Sharepoint Group
# --------------------------------------------------------
function Add-SSUser {
    Param(  [string]$account,
            [string]$displayname,
            [string]$email,
            [string]$sitecollectionurl,
            [string]$group,
            [string]$date)

    Get-SPWeb -Identity $sitecollectionurl | foreach-object {  
            $identityClaimWindowsNTAccount = "i:0#.w|$account"
            [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUser] $ssUser =
                $_.EnsureUser($identityClaimWindowsNTAccount)
            $_.Groups.GetByName($group).AddUser($ssUser)
            $_.Groups.GetByName($group).Update()
            Set-SPUser -Identity $ssUser -Web $_.Url -Group $group
            # Update properties
            $ssUser.Email = $email
            $ssUser.Name = $displayname
            $ssUser.Notes = "[[$date]]"
            $ssUser.Update()
            #Write-Host $ssUser.Xml
    }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code that you have now? The only thing i see that is odd is some spelling errors that i dont know where you declared the variables so it might just be cosmetic. `$_spDisplayNamee` and `last-modied-date`

Comment: @Matt Well... there are probably a lot of things wrong with the script, i will update my post to mention some of my doubts